# How can I remove a previously applied Fade effect in Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I applied a Fade effect to a video clip using Kdenlive. How can I remove this Fade effect again?

[image]

Comment: apparently the hardest thing to do in the world lol. how un-intuitive this is :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the fade effect, click on the clip to which you applied the fade effect (In this case I used "Fade to black", visible as the red triangle at the end of the clip), and then delete the effect in the "Effects stack" tab by clicking the "X". Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Make sure you have "Effect stack" checked in the "View" menu for this to work. I hope I understand your question right, let me know if you haven't and this is not what you want to do.

Comment: That was the right hint, thank you! However, on version 16.04.1, the view is called `Properties`.

Answer (score 2):

I place the cursor (via left click on mouse) over the actual "fade" symbol between the clips, click the cursor and the symbol changes colour to red, then I use the "delete" key on the keyboard and the effect is removed. The same way as I remove a clip. That works with Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Kdenlive vers 0.9.6, and with my latest Ubuntu 16.04LTS, Kdenlive vers 15.12.3. Best of luck.